# Integrate Jaeger open tracing in my django project

Tags: python, django, jaeger, opentracing

In my Django project i would to integrate open tracing tecnique using Jaeger.
I installed a Jaeger operator on my kubernetes cluster:

[image]
[image]

So in my django project i install some packages as:

- django-opentracing
- jaeger-client
- opentracing

then in my django settings.py i do:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django_opentracing.OpenTracingMiddleware',
...
```

and at the end of setting i do:

```
import django_opentracing

OPENTRACING_TRACE_ALL = True

config = Config(
    config={ # usually read from some yaml config
        'sampler': {
            'type': 'const',
            'param': 1,
        },
        'local_agent': {
            'reporting_host': '10.128.33.41', #My k8s Service Cluster IP endpoint
            'reporting_port': '8383',
        },
        'logging': True,
    },
    service_name='jaeger-operator-metrics',
    validate=True,
)
# this call also sets opentracing.tracer
tracer = config.initialize_tracer()
OPENTRACING_TRACING = django_opentracing.DjangoTracing(tracer)
```

So i started my application , no errors all seems domìne but the question is:
How can i see my jaeger dashboard for look at captured events, logging etc?
There is something i have not doing?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

- Why are you using the port 8383?
- Did you define it manually in your deployment?

By default, the [Jaeger agent](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.27/deployment/#agent) exposes the port `6831` for receiving spans with the [format supported by the Python client library](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.27/client-features/).

Comment: I added a "Hi Manuel" at the beginning of the comment but SO just hides it 

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to OpenTelemetry and use that python library, it's more supported and advanced. We are in the process of deprecating the Jaeger instrumentation based on OpenTracing. It will still work, but there will be no more enhancements or work on it.